# One object per each table at PHP OOP?

Tags: php, database, oop

I was wondering it is a good idea to creat one object (one class) at PHP for each table on the DB.

I have for example 3 tables: user, video, rating

Rating is just a table with **idUser**, **idVideo** and the **rating** the user gives to the video. 
Lets say, its a relation with an attribute converted to table on the DB.

I have created two classes at my system: **user**, **video**

Should i create another class for rating? Or i should get the rating info through a method inside user or video?

Comment: What does this have to do with java?

Comment: Why, oh ,why? If you want this sort of OO madness just use an existing  ORM if you must, instead of reinventing one, badly.

Comment: Meet ORIM: http://www.agiledata.org/essays/impedanceMismatch.html

Comment: Which one could i use then Tyler?

Comment: I do not think this is a question that can be answered properly as it will be based on the situation and opinion. You are the only one that can answer this question. Good design would call for consistency and structure. Getting the job done in a timely manner sometimes requires tasks like these be skipped. It can go both ways and you are the only one that can make that decision.

Comment: Which are the advantages of using an ORM? I was currently using PDO

Comment: Anyway, using and ORM such as Idiorm, where should i place this stuff then? $all = ORM::for_table('user')->find_many();
At a controller method instead than at a model one??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, create a class.

Even if the advantages are not obvious right away, it will be very useful when you will have to add other attributes like "DateVoted" for example.

Comment: Thanks. It's a clear answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As Tyler Eaves mentioned in a comment, do not re-invent an ORM-like system like too many do. Use something like [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

Comment: I am currently using OPD, is it compatible with it?

Comment: I think i am gonna use Idiorm https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm as its installation is much more simple. (and i have problems with PEAR...)

Comment: will this work for a system which uses stored procedures(mssql) exclusively? doesn't look like it at first glance.